# Laravel - Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times

Tags: php, laravel, mocking

I have this code:

`Facebook.php` Class

```
 public function generateAuthToken($redirectUrl, $code)
    {
        $params = [
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri'  => $redirectUrl,
            'code'          => $code,
        ];
        $params += $this->getClientParams();

        return $this->request('GET',  '/oauth/access_token', $params);
    }
```

This is the code in my Test:

```
public function testData()
{
    $this->instance(Facebook::class, \Mockery::mock(Facebook::class, function ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('generateAuthToken')
            ->once();
    }));
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method generateAuthToken(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0_Curator_Clients_Facebook should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

I also tried to do something like this, but the error is just the same.:

```
    $this->instance(Facebook::class, \Mockery::mock(Facebook::class, function ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('generateAuthToken')
            ->with(['https://google.com', 'code123'])
            ->once();
    }));
```

How do I resolve this? I am new to this mocking part of testing in Laravel.

Thanks!

Comment: Your test is only setting the mock I don't see where you're actually testing anything

Comment: @apokryfos, the ->once() part of the mock is the assertion. It's basically saying that it expects the generateAuthToken function of the Facebook class to be called exactly one time.

Comment: @ClaytonPage Yes but what is it going to be called by? Nothing in the test is expected to that function because the entire test is just setting up the mock